# Issues with Sunfounder relay board

Tags: relay

I recently purchased a Sunfounder single relay board (https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B013GAGFOU) and am attempting to use it with my Pi. I have connected the board's GND, VCC, and SIG wires to Pi pins 2 (5V), 6 (GND), and 7 (GPIO 4), and created a basic script to test functionality:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

pin = 4

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)

try:
    while 1:
        GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.LOW)
        print "low"
        time.sleep(0.5)
        GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.HIGH)
        print "high"
        time.sleep(0.5)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

The expected result is the the relay turns on for half a second and then turns off. However, the relay is being turned on and not turned off at all, despite the pin being cycled.

Interestingly, the status LED on the board is always on.. it is on but dim when the pin is high, and on and full brightness when the pin is low. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, so any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relay is sold for a 5V Arduino.

The description says it is triggered low so it will be ON when you output 0 (0V) and OFF when you output 1 (5V).  But the Pi can't output 5V from a GPIO as it is a 3V3 device.

The relay **may** switch off if you change the GPIO to be an input.

Comment: Bit of a case of me not reading before I hit the buy button. Your suggestion of making it an input worked. Are there any concerns about doing it this way?

Comment: @Timr I don't know.  Hopefully someone with electronics knowledge will comment.